# Black screen on Activity.setRequestedOrientation(...) call in Android

Tags: android, screen-orientation, split-screen

Does anybody know how to cope the problem?
Using the `android.app.Activity#setRequestedOrientation(SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)` method almost always causes the showing a black screen for a split second during the rotation.

But if I rotate the smartphone itself, then the black screen never appears. 
How to get rid of the black screen? Is it the Android issue of the `setRequestedOrientation()` method, or I do something wrong?

EDIT: AFAIK the black screen with `setRequestedOrientation()` call could happen if we have quite heavy layout, when it takes some more time to initialize it in the UI thread. If you try to call `setRequestedOrientation()` for instance in a "Hello World!" app with a light layout, you won't see the black screen. So, the loading on the UI thread can be the cause of the black screen when you rotate with `setRequestedOrientation()`. But, in other hand why it never appears when I rotate the screen changing the phone orientation?

Comment: set orientation before you `setContentView()`

Comment: @Karan Mer - I would. But I need to rotate the screen to landscape by click on the button in the portrait layout. I depends on the user when to click the button.

Answer (score 2):

The only solution I've found.
Consider I want to turn screen to landscape and what do I do:

1. I remove the root Fragment with heavy stuff from the Activity I want to rotate.
2. Inside the Activity I want to rotate I open an empty white Activity for a moment to cover the black screen. The Activity is calling `setRequestedOrientation(SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)` in its `onCreate` callback and closes itself after the timeout = 500 ms. I open/close the Activity with fade-in/fade-out animation.
3. Inside the Activity I want to rotate I call `setRequestedOrientation(SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)` post delayed with 100 ms. This starts the rotation.
4. After the rotation complete, in the `onCreate` I add the removed Fragment back.

That's it. Rotation to landscape is finished and the black screen was completely covered.

Comment: Thanks. After create a emptyActivity, It works perfect.I am not able to see any black screen. Save my day

Answer (score 0):

**Edited:**

I had the same problem. In older versions of android, if the content of the layout is heavy (if it contains high resolution image, etc.), the running activity is trying to re-create the layout to change the orientation but can't achieve this.

As a solution, we can create 2 different layout resources as portrait and landscape, specifying which one we will use and making it easier for the android.